# Run a vue.js page placed in a folder in public_html in direct admin

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, directadmin

I have a direct admin host which wordpress version 5 is installed.
The public_html folder contains the wordpress files (wp-admin,...).
Now i have a vue project which has an "index.html" file and a "static" folder which contains the js files and etc.. 
Now i want to run this vue project like abc.com/vuefolder and the vue runs separately.
When i create a folder "vuefolder" which contains "index.html" and "static" folder of vue project, and upload in public_html folder, the abc.com/vuefolder is accessible but the vue page is not rendered.(the page is empty!)
How should i run the vue page near by the wordpress ?
Thanks.